# WSO2 - Micro-integrator - Connects to Dashboard , but no instances found

Tags: wso2, dashboard, wso2-micro-integrator

Enviroment:

1 Linux Serves
Micro integrator installed (4.1.0)
Micro Integrator Dashboard installed (4.1.0)

The micro-integrator connects to the Dashboard, but when I try to login, the dashboard says "No running micro integrator instances found. Pls start a server a login":

[image]

any help?

Thanks!
Daniel

I reviewed both deployment.toml files, and everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the mi with the dashboard. This config needs to be added at each mi node.

```
[dashboard_config]
dashboard_url = "https://{hostname/ip}:{port}/dashboard/api/"
heartbeat_interval = 5
group_id = "mi_dev"
node_id = "dev_node_2"
```

More information can be found in here[1].
[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/mi-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/#step-2-configure-the-mi-servers

Comment: Thanks, I already did that. same result: This is the log. any other clue?

INFO {DashboardServer} - WSO2 Micro Integration Monitoring Dashboard started.
 INFO {DashboardServer} - Login to Micro Integrator Dashboard : 'https://indutopds02.localdomain:9743/login'
INFO {HeartBeatDelegate} - New node dev_node_2 in group : mi_dev is registered. Inserting heartbeat information
ERROR {LoginDelegate} - No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start the MI dashboard first and after the dashboard is up and running start the MI server. Please verify the configs you have added with the configurations mentioned here[1].

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/mi-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/

Comment: Thank you, but yes, the MI runs after the dashboard and after de API mgr too.  Also, the dashboard . The dashboard registers de MI as per below log line,  but when I try to login it says that no MI is running.... 

New node dev_node_2 in group : mi_dev is registered. Inserting heartbeat information ERROR {LoginDelegate} - No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login.

Comment: Can you verify whether you have not changed the default "-DenableManagementApi=true" system parameter value in micro-integrator.sh? If the "-DenableManagementApi=false" then the behavior you have observed is expected

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've discovered the solution. Despite searching the Internet, none of the solutions provided worked for this problem. Even the official configuration [step-2-configure-the-mi-servers](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/mi-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/#step-2-configure-the-mi-servers) mentioned in one of the answers didn't resolve the issue.

The positive aspect is that I was able to successfully start up and log in to the dashboard via the Integration Studio while developing artifacts. This led me to read the configuration file "IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\conf\development.toml" of the embedded MI, where I finally found the solution.

All we need to do is configure the MI with the dashboard in the following way:

```ini
 [dashboard_config]
 dashboard_url = "https://localhost:9743/dashboard/api/"
```

Remember no `heartbeat_interval`, `group_id` and `node_id`.

When you see the following logs:

```
INFO {AuthenticationHandlerAdapter} - User admin logged in successfully
```

in the MI terminal and the following logs:

```
INFO {HeartBeatDelegate} - New node xxx in group : default is registered. Inserting heartbeat information
INFO {InMemoryDataManager} - Inserting heartbeat details of node xxx in group default
INFO {MiArtifactsManager} - Fetching artifacts from node xxx in group default
INFO {InMemoryDataManager} - Adding serverInfo of node xxx in group default
```

in the MI Dashboard terminal, it means the problem is solved.